# Laravel 5 - how to retrieve results from table for every date, even if entries do not exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a table named `daily_data` that has a `date` field.  I would like to be able, through the Query Builder interface, return a result for every row in a range of dates, even if there is no entry for a given date (return null values in those cases)

From digging around, one suggestion seems to be generating a dynamic list of dates in the range, and then doing a join with the table.  This seems like a fairly nice way to solve the problem, but I can not find any examples of this in Laravel.  I would prefer to have the full set of results returned from Query Builder rather than having to loop through the results in PHP, detecting/adding empty fields after the query.

If there is a better way to achieve this with Laravel/Query Builder, I would gladly hear it.

In the meantime, I found this code for generating a range of dates on SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38f7db/92.  It does what it claims to, and I did adapt it to work in Laravel.  It is basically everything contained in the DB::select below.  Here is my attempt to combine it with a join to get the results I'm looking for:

```
    $dates = DB::select(DB::raw(
        'SELECT a.Date as Date FROM
          (SELECT "2017-11-15" - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a)) DAY AS Date
           FROM
             (SELECT 0 AS a
              UNION ALL SELECT 1
              UNION ALL SELECT 2
              UNION ALL SELECT 3
              UNION ALL SELECT 4
              UNION ALL SELECT 5
              UNION ALL SELECT 6
              UNION ALL SELECT 7
              UNION ALL SELECT 8
              UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a CROSS
           JOIN
             (SELECT 0 AS a
              UNION ALL SELECT 1
              UNION ALL SELECT 2
              UNION ALL SELECT 3) AS b) a
        where a.Date between "2017-11-01" and "2017-11-15"'))
        ->leftJoin(
            'daily_data',
            function($join) {
                $join->on("Date", "=", "daily_data.date");
            }
        );
```

I get the error:

> [2017-11-16 01:23:16] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function leftJoin() on array

I can understand that this doesn't work as using `DB::table` would...but is there a different way to accomplish what I am trying to do here?

I have verified that the part of the query generating the dates does work in returning an appropriate list of dates.  (see below for the code, basically the same as above without the join, and the output it gives).

> ```
>    $dates = DB::select(DB::raw(
>         'SELECT a.Date as Date FROM
>           (SELECT "2017-11-15" - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a)) DAY AS Date
>            FROM
>              (SELECT 0 AS a
>               UNION ALL SELECT 1
>               UNION ALL SELECT 2
>               UNION ALL SELECT 3
>               UNION ALL SELECT 4
>               UNION ALL SELECT 5
>               UNION ALL SELECT 6
>               UNION ALL SELECT 7
>               UNION ALL SELECT 8
>               UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a CROSS
>            JOIN
>              (SELECT 0 AS a
>               UNION ALL SELECT 1
>               UNION ALL SELECT 2
>               UNION ALL SELECT 3) AS b) a
>         where a.Date between "2017-11-01" and "2017-11-15" '));
> ```

and the output... (a list of dates between 2017-11-01 and 2017-11-15):

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Date] => 2017-11-15
    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Date] => 2017-11-05
    )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Date] => 2017-11-14
    )
...
```

)

(I know its not ordered but I am sure I can fix that, just trying to get the basic idea down for now)

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this raw query instead of using leftJoin() method

```
$dates = DB::select(DB::raw('
    SELECT a.Date AS DATE
    FROM
    (
        SELECT "2017-11-15" - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a)) DAY AS DATE
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 UNION ALL
            SELECT 6 UNION ALL
            SELECT 7 UNION ALL
            SELECT 8 UNION ALL
            SELECT 9) AS a CROSS
            JOIN
            (
                SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL
                SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT 2 UNION ALL
                SELECT 3
            ) AS b
        ) a
    LEFT JOIN daily_data c ON a.Date=c.date
    WHERE a.Date BETWEEN "2017-11-01" AND "2017-11-15"
    ORDER BY a.Date'));
```

Comment: The idea of just using the raw query for the whole thing has gotten me farther.  I do need to add some more constraints and stuff, but this has me on the right path, thanks.